# Run shell command against every version of the same file in git

Tags: git, shell, zsh

Consider a file `my_file` in a git repo. I would like to **run a shell command** (e.g. `wc -l $FILE_VERSION`) against each of the last `K` versions of this file in a given branch (e.g. master).

By **version** I mean unique snapshots of the file (i.e. when the file **changed**). More specifically, as an example, the last `K=4` versions:

```
master   <file_changed>       v4
master~1 <file_not_changed>   
master~2 <file_changed>       v3
master~3 <file_changed>       v2
master~4 <file_not_changed>   
master~5 <file_changed>       v1
```

How can I approach this problem with git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like so

```
for i in $(git log --pretty='%h' -- my_file)
do
   echo "$i $(git show ${i}:my_file | wc -l)"
done
```

This doesn't actually check out the file. Simply displays it. You can, if you want, redirect that into a file and run a more complex command on it. For `wc`, this is sufficient. It also uses the `--pretty` parameter to git log so that we get only what we need rather than the whole commit information.

This will go all the way back but you can narrow it down to just a few commits using a `head`

Comment: Good approach, but as a shell-script best-practices note: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Consider instead: `while read -r i; do ...; done < <(git log --pretty=%h -- my_file)`

Comment: Much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the commits:

```
git log "$file" \
    | grep '^commit ' \
    | head -n 10 \
    | while read _c id ; do
          git checkout "$id"
          echo "$id"
          wc -l < "$file"
      done
```